# Does importing a module in Python execute all the module's imports in local scope?

Tags: python, python-import

```
$ python -c 'import urllib.parse; print(urllib.error.HTTPError)'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'error'
```

That's expected. I haven't imported `urllib.error` module.

```
$ python -c 'import urllib.request; print(urllib.request.HTTPError)'
<class 'urllib.error.HTTPError'>
```

This one too. `urllib.request` [imports](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.0a2/Lib/urllib/request.py#L102) `urllib.error`:

```
from urllib.error import URLError, HTTPError, ContentTooShortError
```

So the names are available via `urllib.request`.

```
$ python -c 'import urllib.request; print(urllib.error.HTTPError)'
<class 'urllib.error.HTTPError'>
```

But not this one. What makes me able to access `HTTPError` via `urllib.error`? I've read [the](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html) [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#import), but saw no clues there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, let's see:

```
import urllib.parse
globals()
```

You will see an item:

```
'urllib': <module 'urllib' from 'C:\\Users\\XXXX\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35\\lib\\urllib\\__init__.py'>
```

Then, try `dir(urllib)`, you will see:

```
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', 'parse']
```

So there is a `parse` in `urllib`, but not `request` or `error`. Because `parse` doesn't import them.

Now let's go to `urllib.request`:

```
import urllib.request
globals()
```

Get an item:

```
'urllib': <module 'urllib' from 'C:\\Users\\XXXX\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35\\lib\\urllib\\__init__.py'>
```

It is the same as `import urllib.parse`.

Then try `dir(urllib)` again:

```
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', 'error', 'parse', 'request', 'response']
```

There are `'error', 'parse', 'request', 'response'` in it. Why? **Because `urllib.request` imports them**.

Let me try and explain it in more details. Importing `urllib.request` first imports `urllib`, then `urllib.request`. Importing `urllib` gives us `urllib` symbol in local scope, representing module having been imported. Importing `urllib.request` imports `urllib.error` among other things. Which adds `error` symbol to `urllib` module. And **since we have reference to `urllib`**, that makes us able to access `urllib.error` after importing `urllib.request`. Consider the following example:

`./main.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import a.b
print(a.c.c)   # 2
print(d.e.e)   # NameError
```

`./a/b.py`

```
import a.c
import d.e
b = 1
```

`./a/c.py`

```
c = 2
```

`./d/e.py`:

```
e = 3
```

Comment: I think, "Because urllib.request imports them" doesn't cut it. From my point of view, "module A importing module B, and module B importing module C" doesn't mean that module C gets available from module A. What do you say of [my explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47459717/does-importing-a-module-in-python-execute-all-the-modules-imports-in-local-scop#comment81876008_47459951)? On a side note, your showing how to inspect the matter was pretty educational.

Comment: The critical point is that no matter how you use `import A.B.C...`. You first get the access to top scope `A`. So you will have access to every submodules if they have been imported somewhere.

Comment: I'd say the critical point is that `import` can affect parent scopes. If I `import` `A.B` and `A.B` `import`s `A.C`, I'd probably expect to find `C` under `A.B.A.C`. Not that it's the right thing to do, just what I'd expect.

Comment: This is designed to efficiently manage module importing. Every module in python will be imported only once. If it works as you expect, suppose `import A.B` and `A.B` import `A.C`, then you get `A.B.A.C`, but after you also manually `import A.C`, in this case, what are you having now? Two identical modules `A.B.A.C` and `A.C`.

Comment: Although we can make `C` of `A.B.A` a reference of `C` of `A`, this will disturb the scope in such a simple example, isn't it?

Comment: Good point. To make it clear, I didn't mean that Python's behavior is wrong, just unexpected, at least to me.

Comment: Please amend your answer based on the discussion we had, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Unsure whether it is what you expected, but this is *by design*. Is you look at the sources of urllib/parse.py and urllib/request.py you will see an important difference: the former only import the re, sys and collections modules when the latter (in addition to other unrelated modules) also explicitely imports symbols from urllib.error, urllib.parse and urllib.response.

That is the reason why you find them available even if the import was not in your own source file.

A more detailed answer would require a detailed description of Python import machinery and is far beyond what is appropriate in a SO answer. Please refer to the official documentation for a more in depth explaination.

Comment: Can you at least give some clues regarding what makes `urllib.error` available? I believe I've read the description of that machinery and am still at a loss. And by the way, should I only import `urllib.request` then and access all the methods via `urllib.request` only? Or each via corresponding module?

Comment: Let me try to explain it. `import urllib.request` == `import urllib` + `import urllib.request`. `import urllib` finds and loads the module, then binds it into local scope as `urllib`. `import urllib.request` finds and loads the module and binds it into `urllib`'s scope as `request`. While loading `urllib.request`, it imports `urllib.error` which probably binds the latter into `urllib`'s scope as `error`. That's what makes us able to access `HTTPError` via `urllib.error.HTTPError`. Am I wrong?